# matplotlib plotting question in python to show the time spend on each state

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Lest consider I have two in a path, state 0 and 1.
Let's consider, when I'm following a path state:0 spent a certain amount of time at 0 and a certain amount of time at 1.

For example;

```
State    Time spend on each state 
  0      1.099190425147403394e+00 
  1      2.109956038727701433e+00 
  0      4.392933181897487049e-01 
  1      1.026012186825693284e+00 
  0      1.339228438495629003e+00 
  1      1.327323517945566023e+00
```

How do I make a plot where I can show that when I'm following a path where the states 0 and 1 appear alternatively (Like the 1st column) which the y-axis and x-axis will be the time where it will show how long each state spend their time (The width of the horizontal straight line will represent the time spent on each state) like the image below using python matplotlib,
[image]
state spend a certain amount of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
plt.step(df['Time spend on each state'].cumsum().shift(fill_value=0), 
     df['State'], where='post')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The states and time spend on each states these two datas are in two different file. Is there a way to plot by using two different file data

Comment: @IndraniChoudhuri  The answer is to the point of your question. Accepting it is correct way to thank. Further question can be post as a new question.